# Where do added listitems inherit the "ProgId" property?

Tags: content-type

```
       /// <summary>
   /// An item was added.
   /// </summary>
   public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
   {
       base.ItemAdded(properties);

       if(!IsMyCustomListItem(properties.ListItem))
       {
           return;
       }

       var progId = properties.ListItem.ProgId;
       // If a content type of word doc 
       // was added for example, this property would be of string value Word.Document
       properties.ListItem.ProgId = "MyIdentifier.Identifier";
       properties.ListItem.Update();
   }
```

This is my current solution for setting the ProgId attribute for my custom listitems that are of custom content type. DocumentSet, Word documents and many other files **inherit** this attribute from somewhere - **where** exactly ?

From what i understood, this is a meta tag for html documents - i have no idea what to add to my feature.

Edit:
Tried this in content type CAML, ProgId still not getting set for added listItems:

```
<ContentType ID="0x0120008d88d270aed24e86b061dd7977c54f31"
         ProgId="MyIdentifier.Identifier"
```

/>